# Generar números aleatorios en una lista sin repetir dada la longitud de un lista [Unity 3D]

Tags: unity3d, unity

Estoy intentando generar números aleatorios dada la longitud de una lista e ir añadiéndolos a una lista. En caso de que se haya generado el número, genere otro número diferente.

El problema es que no pueden salir en orden según el juego que estoy haciendo por eso no me sirve un bucle `for{}`.

Este es mi código, pero se bloquea porque parece que entra en un bucle infinito.

**¿Alguien me podría ayudar?**

```
void GenerarAleatoriosSinRepetir(){

     List <int> numerosGuardados = new List<int> ();
     posicionAleatoria = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count);

     while(!numerosGuardados.Contains(posicionAleatoria)) {
            posicionAleatoria = posicionAleatoria;
     }
     numerosGuardados.Add (posicionAleatoria);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola Eduardo!

Lo que propones es bastante sencillo. Tu lógica era buena, pero fallaste al final.Tu `while` no es correcto, es más no sirve para nada en tu código. Para que te generase lo que deseas, deberías cambiar el `numerosGuardados.Add(posicionAleatoria)` dentro del `while`, sustituyendo a `posicionAleatoria = posicionAleatoria;`.

Además, veo que el código que te da error está dentro de un método por lo que tendrías que llamar a ese método las veces necesarias para completar la lista. Como no se cual es el resto de código te aconsejo que incluyas tu código dentro de un `for`.

Te paso un código de ejemplo con tus variables:

```
List<int> numerosGuardados = new List<int>();
int posicionAleatoria;
for (int i = 0; i < listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count; i++)
{
  do {
     posicionAleatoria = Random.Range (0, listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count);
  } while (numerosGuardados.Contains(posicionAleatoria));
  numerosGuardados.Add(posicionAleatoria);
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo.